# Search input with two buttons in semantic UI

Tags: angularjs, angular

Look at thr following link, please:
http://legacy.semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html

Is it possible to create a search field with two buttons? I mean a magnify glass button to search, and - second - a cross button for undoing search. Is it possible?

Comment: You want an input box followed by 2 buttons where one should be enabled when we start entering a text in the input field and on click, should do the search and the other button should clear the input filed, right?

Comment: @VijayMenon Yes, exactly